# AVPlayer Crashes on Device When Dismissing View

Tags: ios, avplayer, iphone-6, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm having an issue with the AVPlayer. I've tried many solutions but it still crashes after I move to a different view.

```
class GuideVideo : BaseViewController{

var avPlayer: AVPlayer?
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    generateVideo()
}

func generateVideo () {
    let videoURLWithPath = data["VideoUrl"]
    let videoFilePath = NSURL(string: videoURLWithPath!)

    let avAsset: AVAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(videoFilePath) as! AVAsset
    let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)

    avPlayerLayer!.frame = self.videoView.bounds
    self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
    avPlayer!.play()
}
```

I've also tried removing the observers from it since I assume the crash is related to a nil observer.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        if self.avPlayerLayer != nil {
            self.avPlayerLayer!.player.pause()
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self.avPlayerLayer!)
            self.avPlayerLayer!.removeFromSuperlayer()
            self.avPlayerLayer = nil
        }
        self.avPlayer!.pause()
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer()
    })
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Nothing works and the crash provides no data. Either it crashes without indicating a line or a general

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   * Import thing to note is that this crash only happens on the iPhone 6/6+. Our iPhone 5C handles the class well.
>   * I only get the crash after moving to another view controller or a different navigation stack, but a few seconds after the view had been dismissed.

Thank you, been sitting on this for the better part of 2 days now.

**EDIT:** The issue is apparently related to the SWReveal. It deallocates instances before their lifecycle is over.
Accepted the best solution, but the problem is related to SWReveal.

Comment: `viewWillDisappear` is already called on the main thread. So what is the purpose of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`?

Comment: If you cannot determine the crash line any other way, maybe you can intersperse your code with lots of logging (`println`) so you can determine what is the last line that executes before the crash happens.

Comment: When I was using breakpoints to see where the app crashed it stopped crashing so I wanted to check if it was thread related.

Comment: Look in your Breakpoints navigator. Do you, by any chance, have an Exceptions breakpoint?

Comment: No. I've also tried to check where exactly it crashes and it crashes after the view has already disappeared. Which is why I added the removeObserver.

Comment: Try turning on Zombies?

Comment: With the zombies on I get a `UIActivityIndicatorView release]: message sent to deallocated instance` error. Which is interesting since I don't use UIActivityIndicator at all.

Comment: Do you use table view refresh control? (I'm trying to think of things that might _have_ a UIActivityIndicatorView internally...)

Comment: No. It could be related to the fact the video is loaded from a remote server. I'm changed it to a local video and it seems to be more stable, not perfect but stable.
And thank you :) I'm just hoping this will help someone somewhere in the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try using the MPMoviePlayerController instead of the AVPlayer, for simple solutions, the MPMoviePlayerController has an easier API.
2. make the MPMoviePlayerController a global instance making it accessible through the whole app, and then initialize it when you need it.
3. Try playing the videos locally first and check if it solves the problem